# Determinant of a matrix and chech whether it is non negative definite or not

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $V = \{ f : [0,1] \to \mathbb R | f$ is a polynomial of degree less than or equal to n $\}$. Let $f_j(x)  = x^j$ for $0\leq j \leq n$ and let $A$ be the $(n+1) \times (n+1)$  given by $a_{ij} = \int_0^1 f_i(x)f_j(x) dx$. Then which of the followings are true.
>
> 1. $\dim V = n$
> 2. $\dim V >n$
> 3. $A$ is non negative definite.
> 4. $\det A >0$.

Clearly the option 1. is false and 2. is correct

I knnow the matrix $A$ is

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{00} & a_{01} & a_{02} & \cdots & a_{0n}\\
a_{10} & a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n}\\
a_{20} & a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_{n0} & a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \cdots & a_{nn}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} & \cdots & \frac{1}{n+1}\\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} &\frac{1}{4} & \cdots & \frac{1}{n+2}\\
\frac{1}{3}& \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{5} & \cdots & \frac{1}{n+3}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\frac{1}{n+1} & \frac{1}{n+2} & \frac{1}{n+3} & \cdots & \frac{1}{2n+1}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I am unable to find the determinant of the matrix $A$, so please help to find the determinant of the matrix and the matrix $A$ is non negative definnite or not. Thank you

Comment: There's some problem with the definition of $f_j$, since you've mentioned it's valid for $1\le j\le n$ whereas later on you've used $f_0$. (For example in $a_{00}$)

Comment: Sorry, $j$ varies from 0 to n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: for any real vector $v$, express $v^T A v$ as an integral.

Comment: Sir I know that if $v^t Av \geq 0$, then $A$ is non negative definte and $det A >0$ . let $v^T = (x_1, x_2 , \cdots, x_{n+1} )$, then $v^TAv = x_1^2 + \frac{x_2^2}{3} +\frac{x_3^2}{5} \cdots \frac{x_{n+1}^2}{2n+1}+x_1 +2\frac{x_1x_3}{3} +2\frac{x_1x_4}{4} + \cdots +2\frac{x_1x_{n+1}}{n+1}  +2\frac{x_2x_3}{4} +2\frac{x_2x_4}{5}+\cdots +2\frac{x_2x_5}{6} \cdots +2\frac{x_2x_{n+1}}{n+2} \cdots+2\frac{x_nx_{n+1}}{2n}$

Comment: I am unable to proceed further

Comment: $$v^T A v  = \sum_{i,j} \int _0^1 v_i f_i(x) v_j f_j(x) \; dx = \int_0^1 \left( \sum_i v_i f_i(x) \right)^2\; dx$$